# Chicken Scheme - Error: unbound variable: chicken-home

Tags: chicken-scheme

I'm trying to install with scheme with emacs + geiser, and get on the geiser:

```
Starting Geiser REPL for chicken ... process-lines: ~/lisp/chicken/bin/csi exited with status 70
```

so I remembered that I forgot to configure what was requested here(https://wiki.call-cc.org/emacs):

1. Install the necessary support eggs.

**$ chicken-install -s apropos chicken-doc**

2. Update the Chicken documentation database.

**$ cd `csi -p '(chicken-home)'`**

**$ curl http://3e8.org/pub/chicken-doc/chicken-doc-repo.tgz | sudo tar zx**

However when executing:

**cd `csi -p '(chicken-home)'`**

Nothing happens, so check what I'm getting with:

**./csi -p '(chicken-home)'**

And I receive the following:

```
something@something:~/lisp/chicken/bin$ ./csi -p '(chicken-home)'

Error: unbound variable: chicken-home

    Call history:

    <syntax>      (##core#begin (##core#require library scheme#) (##core#require library chicken.base#) (##core#requir...
    <syntax>      (##core#require library scheme#)
    <syntax>      (##sys#load-library (##core#quote library))
    <syntax>      (##core#quote library)
    <syntax>      (##core#require library chicken.base#)
    <syntax>      (##sys#load-library (##core#quote library))
    <syntax>      (##core#quote library)
    <syntax>      (##core#begin (##core#require expand chicken.syntax#))
    <syntax>      (##core#require expand chicken.syntax#)
    <syntax>      (##sys#load-library (##core#quote expand))
    <syntax>      (##core#quote expand)
    <eval>    (##sys#load-library (##core#quote library))
    <eval>    (##sys#load-library (##core#quote library))
    <eval>    (##sys#load-library (##core#quote expand))
    <syntax>      (chicken-home)
    <eval>    (chicken-home)    <--
```

*Note*:

```
Chicken version: CHICKEN 5

OS: LINUX
```

> UP

In version 5 I discovered that it is necessary to:

```
(import (chicken platform))
```

to call:

```
(chicken-home)
```

however I downloaded it:

```
curl http://3e8.org/pub/chicken-doc/chicken-doc-repo.tgz | sudo tar zx
```

to the correct directory(chicken-home):

```
/home/something/lisp/chicken//share/chicken/
```

and yet I receive:

```
"Starting Geiser REPL for chicken ... process-lines: ~/lisp/chicken/bin/csi exited with status 70"
```

Comment: Are you using CHICKEN 5? That would explain the error message, `(chicken-home)` isn't available by default.

Comment: @wasamasa yes, CHICKEN 5.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, first I was using this file:

http://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/geiser/0.10/geiser-0.10.tar.gz

It's broken, I always get:

```
"csi exited with status 70"
```

So I downloaded the git version:

```
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/geiser.git
```

So I try to start the geise:

```
M-x run-geiser RET chicken RET
```

And I get the error:

```
"car: Symbol’s function definition is void: seq-filter"
```

Then there is something happening in the file "geiser/elisp/geiser-chicken.el", they forgot to add the line:

```
(require 'seq)
```

Now it's working.

***!Important:*** In emacs <= version 24 "seq-filter" does not even exist. I do not know the exact version that was added "seq-filter", from what I saw in the Emacs documentation, not documented by version, at least I did not find it, so I do not know very well, but it was tested that in Emacs 24 there is no such library.